# Oracle: Sum cell values for same id but different groups

Tags: oracle

I am trying to sum the values of same id but for different group (1000, 2000). Here is the table.

| ID | GROUP | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1000 | 11 |
| 101 | 2000 | 10 |
| 101 | 5000 | 18 |

What I want as output

| ID | GROUP | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 3000 | 21 |
| 101 | 5000 | 18 |

How do I sum the VALUE column and name the Group column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the groups 1000 and 2000 together like below. (Hope you don't have "GROUP" = -9999999999 in your table)

```sql
select ID, sum("GROUP")"GROUP", sum("VALUE")"VALUE"
from your_table
group by ID, case when "GROUP" in (1000, 2000) then -9999999999 else "GROUP" end
;
```

Comment: Thank you @MDO. This solved my question. There was a little modification in the questions, GROUP 1000,2000 needs to be one group 1000. I used decode for GROUP and sum the VALUES. Thanks once again.

Comment: Glad to see I could help. I appreciate your feedback!